# Setting Spinner mode in android API 10

Tags: android

I am creating a spinner using android API level 10. I need to have the list in a *dropdown* (comb-box) fashion and not in a dialog form. Unlike API 12 it does not have "mode" which can be set to either MODE_DIALOG  or MODE_DROPDOWN. 
Please suggest me a non-constructor solution since I am getting the spinner from xml.

Answer (score 0):

android:spinnerMode="dialog" or android:spinnerMode="dropdown"